# is it possible to inject the css into tsx when using vite to compile public typescript library

Tags: css, typescript, vite

I have a public library that was compiled by [vite](https://vitejs.dev/guide/) right now. The public library contains some `tsx` file and `css` file. Now I found when I import the tsx component that did not contain the css style. Is it possible to pack the css file when compile the public library? I have tried to using the lib `vite-plugin-css-injected-by-js` https://www.npmjs.com/package/vite-plugin-css-injected-by-js, config the plugin in `vite.config.ts` like this:

```
export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [
        react({
            
        }),
        cssInjectedByJsPlugin(),
        dts({
            insertTypesEntry: true,
        }),
    ],
}
```

seems did not work. what should I do to inject the css file when using vite `"vite": "^4.3.5",`?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use the following option to inject CSS into all entry files.

```
cssInjectedByJsPlugin({
  relativeCSSInjection: true 
})
```

**Note:** this option is still experimental.

https://github.com/marco-prontera/vite-plugin-css-injected-by-js#relativecssinjection-boolean

Or you can use the jsAssetsFilterFunction option that provides a callback where you can filter using the filename.